# Problems displaying French accented characters in UTF-8

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8

I'm working on a French language site built in CakePHP.  I have tried multiple functions to try and convert the text into UTF-8 and display properly, but have had no success so far - any accented letters are displaying as a black diamond with a question mark.  They do display correctly when I change the char set in the browser to ISO-8859-1, but I'd like to make the while site UTF-8 compliant.  I have used:

html_entity_decode($string, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
htmlspecialchars($string, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
utf8_encode

but no cigar.  The page is set to UTF-8 in the header

And the MySQL database is using UTF-8 too.  How can I get the accented characters to display properly in UTF-8?

Comment: Sorry, didn't know how to accept answers, have done it now

Comment: in general, you have nothing to convert. just store user text without any encoding and than display it back using htmlspecialchars only.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check your `@@character_set_results`. By default, MySQL uses `latin1`, not `utf8`. Try `SET NAMES utf8` or [mysqli::set_charset](http://be.php.net/mysqli.set_charset).

Update: here is how you might check the character sets in use:

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%char%';
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                      |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8                       | 
| character_set_connection | utf8                       | 
| character_set_database   | utf8                       | 
| character_set_filesystem | binary                     | 
| character_set_results    | utf8                       | 
| character_set_server     | utf8                       | 
| character_set_system     | utf8                       | 
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ | 
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
```

Read more on [dev.mysql.com](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset.html).

Answer (score 5):

**First:** Check your php files encoding! I work on Mac, I use [Coda](http://www.panic.com/coda) to program, and it has an option to convert charset's, sometimes i get troubles like this and converting to UTF-8 always fix them. I think that Notepad++ can do that on windows. (If you do this on your PHP files, every strings on them will not need the functions `htmlspecialchars()`, `html_entity_decode`, etc )

**Second:** if you are using HTML Output, check if you have `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />` on your header...

**Third:** Do what @janmoesen said on your MySQL DB.

Tell me something about that.

Comment: you are da man. I never thought it could of been caused by the actual file encoding.

Answer (score 3):

I just fixed a very similar problem with accented characters not displaying. My database table is utf-8 encoded and my html header is correctly set for utf-8.

I hadn't specified a charset for my MySQL connection, in my case I'm using PDO.

```
$this->pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname;charset=utf8;", $username, $password);
```

No problems now!

Answer (score 1):

In case this helps anyone using PHP Classes.

My solution was to set Character Encoding to my Connection.

```
//connect to MySQL and select DB
public function open_connection() {
    $this->connection = new mysqli( DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME );
    if ( !$this->connection ) {
        die( "Database connection failed: " . mysqli_error() );
    }
    mysqli_set_charset($this->connection,"utf8");
}
```